# jQuery $.post method. Requesting the data from called cshtml page. How can I check that it works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, request, .post

I am using a `$.post` function to send some data collected from an input box to a separate file, `post_new_activity.cshtml` . I am also using alert boxes for debugging purposes to see which line of code I get to. I am trying to pass one variable 'activity' to the external file. The problem I'm getting is that I'm not sure if the post method is working as only one alert box pops up (the one in the `.click` function) and then their is no error message or no more alert boxes. How can I check if my `$.post` is working.

I am really really new to jQuery so any help at all would really be appreciated.

Here are some code snippets:

the modal with the input box and the button with id="modal_btn_submit"

```
<div id="modal_add_activity" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">Add an Activity to the Database</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label for="modal_activity_input">Enter activity name: </label>
        <input id="modal_activity_input" value="">
        <br>
        <p>Once you press <b class="text-success">Add to Webpage </b>the action can not be undone</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="modal_btn_submit" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Add to Webpage</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery function that calls the $.post method

```
 $("#modal_btn_submit").click(function () {
      var activity = $("#modal_activity_input").val();
      alert("Adding " + activity);

      $.post("post_new_activity.cshtml", $(activity),
           function (data, status) {
             alert("Activity: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
           });
    });
```

post_new_activity.cshtml which is called by the $.post method

```
@{
  alert("cshtml file loaded");
  var activity= Request["add_activity"];
  alert("From cshtml file activity: " + activity);
  var string_return= activity + " Added.";
  Json.Write (string_return, Response.Output); 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post_new_activity.cshtml` expecting `add_activity` property at `POST` ? , see `var activity= Request["add_activity"];` . Though `js` at Question `POST` data appear to be `$("#modal_activity_input").val();` wrapped in call to `jQuery()` , which returns a jQuery object , at `$.post("post_new_activity.cshtml", $(activity)` ?

Try posting data as `{"add_activity": activity}`

```
$.post("post_new_activity.cshtml", {"add_activity": activity},
  function (data, status) {
    alert("Activity: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

Comment: So @guest271314 I have changed the $.post function to
     $("#modal_btn_submit").click(function () {
          var activity = $("#modal_activity_input").val();
          alert("Adding " + activity);
          
          $.post("post_new_activity.cshtml", {"add_activity": activity},
               function (data, status) {
                 alert("Activity: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
               });
        });

I am still not receiving any alerts from the post_new_activity.cshtml

Comment: Try adding `.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(textStatus, errorThrown) })` chained to `$.post("post_new_activity.cshtml", {"add_activity": activity},
  function (data, status) {
    alert("Activity: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
})` , without semicolon `;`

Answer (score 0):

assuming the cshtml code works, because i don t know it, i d suggest few things about the javascript.

The call to $.post has a weird argument `$(activity)`.

`$(/*string|array|dom element*/)`

is a special funtion from jQuery that is used to evaluate DOM related expressions.

It can, for example, create new DOM element given a string `$('<div></div>');`, you can then append it in the document

`$("body").append($('<span></span>')`.

Or, it can select an existing element from the DOM (keywords : css selectors, sizzle) `$("div");`.

That gives you access to all `div` nodes existing in the document

Finally, a last usage is array iteration, such

`$(['some']).each(function(k,v){ /* */ });`

---

Given that, your usage `$(activity)` seems wrong, as it asks jquery to find / create an element given the value of `$("#modal_activity_input").val()`.

My understanding being that you want to post the string value of that input, not the result of a jQuery expression.

Then, the second argument of `$.post` is expected to be a serializable object. An object containing only plain values, not any references.

You should rewrite it to, as stated by guest271314

```
$.post("post_new_activity.cshtml", {"add_activity": activity},
function (data, status) {
    alert("Activity: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

---

Second question, how to get errors ?

I suspect the cshtml framework answers with a specific HTTP error code when a problem occur, ie 5xx or 4xx instead of 200.

In that case jQuery won t return into your response function, but into an fail handler.

Internally it is using promise implementation (keywords $.defer, $.when, javascript promise, Q).

To catch those errors you need to write it that way,

```
$.post("post_new_activity.cshtml", {"add_activity": activity},
  function (data, status) {
    alert("Activity: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
}).fail(function(){
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

If you wanted to catch every response, whatever theirs status is, you may use `always` handler.

```
$.post("post_new_activity.cshtml", {"add_activity": activity},
  function (data, status) {
    alert("Activity: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
}).fail(function(){
    console.log(arguments);
}).always(function(){
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

As you see they are chainable.

In that example, if it fails, it will execute fail + always handlers.

If it succeed, it will execute the response handler + always handler.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to check your console in this kind of issues,

If you are using **google chrome press f12** key or right click inspect element then you will be able to find the console,

If you are using firefox **Ctrl + Shift + K**,

Also i have created a fiddle below,

```js
$("#modal_btn_submit").click(function () {
      var activity = $("#modal_activity_input").val();
      alert("Adding " + activity);

      $.post("http://stackoverflow.com/", $(activity),
           function (data, status) {
             alert("Activity: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
               console.log(data);
           });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a id="modal_btn_submit" >click</a>

<input type="text" value="1234" id="modal_activity_input"/>
```

Data passing is **working**